# How to make my code cleaner (return statements)

Tags: java, if-statement, return, state-machine

I am programming a simple state machine as practice.
When I have a lot of states with conditions it becomes too unreadable in my opinion.
I want to see in the blink of an eye what state I am returning.

Example how it is now:

```
if  ((currentState.equals(State.s70_SupplyFanStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
        ((currentState.equals(State.s80_ControlStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
        ((currentState.equals(State.s90_LimitMonitoringStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
        ((currentState.equals(State.s99_Fault)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
        ((currentState.equals(State.s100_Interlocked)) && (/**Some statement*/));{
            return State.s00_StandBy;
}
```

The above code cant be folded properly, only the return is folder. So, you continue to see all this:

```
if  (((currentState.equals(State.s70_SupplyFanStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
    ((currentState.equals(State.s80_ControlStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
    ((currentState.equals(State.s90_LimitMonitoringStart)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
    ((currentState.equals(State.s99_Fault)) && (/**Some statement*/)); Or
    ((currentState.equals(State.s100_Interlocked)) && (/**Some statement*/)); {...}
```

What I for example would like to see is something like this:

```
return State.s00_StandBy IF {
    /**statement_1 = true or */
        /**statement_2 = true or
            /**statement_3 = true;*
}
```

so if you fold it you will only see something like this:

```
return State.StandBy IF {...}
```

in the end it would be much better to find certain states when they are lined up like this:

```
return State.StandBy IF {...}

return State.s70_SupplyFanStart IF {...}

return State.s80_ControlStart IF {...}

return State.s90_LimitMonitoringStart IF {...}
```

etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model your states as an enum, and encapsulate the transition logic inside the enums.

So you instead call:

```
return currentState.nextState();
```

Your enum would be something like:

```
public enum State {

    s70_SupplyFanStart {
        @Override
        public State nextState() {
            // if...
            return ...;
        }
    },
    s80_ControlStart {
        @Override
        public State nextState() {
            // if ...
            return ....;
        }
    },
    ....

    public abstract State nextState(); 
}
```

See for example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-simple-state-machine

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more convenient to use `switch` statement for this purpose?

Assuming `currentState` is an instance of `State` enum, the code may be rewritten:

```java
boolean otherCondition = false;
switch (currentState) {
    s70_SupplyFanStart:
        otherCondition = /*statement 1*/; 
        break;
    s80_ControlStart:
        otherCondition = /*statement 2*/; 
        break;
    s90_LimitMonitoringStart:
        otherCondition = /*statement 3*/; 
        break;
    s99_Fault:
        otherCondition = /*statement 4*/; 
        break;
    s100_Interlocked:
        otherCondition = /*statement 5*/; 
        break;
}
if (otherCondition) {
    return State.s00_StandBy;
}
// ...
```

Or with a shorter `switch` syntax from Java 12+:

```java
boolean otherCondition = switch (currentState) {
    s70_SupplyFanStart -> /*statement 1*/; 
    s80_ControlStart -> /* statement 2*/;
    s90_LimitMonitoringStart -> /*statement 3*/;
    s99_Fault -> /*statement 4*/;
    s100_Interlocked -> /*statement 5*/;
    default -> false;
}
if (otherCondition) {
    return State.s00_StandBy;
}
```

Comment: I currently am doing it with a case switch so my Main is clean and readable imo,  i have a method called getState()  which returns an enum state.   getState contains logic between states. in the switch i do this:    switch(getState)   case: state_1 : process(state_1).     and then in the process method i code everything that needs to be executed in a certain state with the if statements.